# Como alterar CSS no Ionic 1

Tags: html, css, ionic

Boa tarde, estou tentando colocar o css no Ionic, algumas coisas funcionaram e outras não. Estudei um pouco de css com [essa apostila](http://fabiorogeriosj.com.br/2016/06/24/Ebook-2-Ionic-Framework-Customizando-e-criando-componentes/), tentei aplicar cores de fundo no `ion-list` do `menu.html`, mas não deu certo, a única coisa que consegui alterar, por enquanto, foi a fonte.

*menu.html*

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="no-text"></ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left"><button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button></ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive"><h1 class="title">Santa Filomena</h1></ion-header-bar>

        <ion-content class="teste">
            <div>
                <img class="full-image" src="img/santa-filomena3.jpg" class="avatar motion spin fade"> 
                <p>Santuário Santa Filomena - Sorocaba/Sp</p> 
            </div>
            <ion-list class="list-custom">
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/principal">principal </ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/missa">Missa</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/adoracao">Adoração</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/doacao">Doação</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/confissao">Confissao</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/santaFilomena">Santa Filomena</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/avisos">Avisos</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/eventosFestas">Eventos e festas</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/secretaria">Secretaria</ion-item>
                <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">Em Desenvolvimento</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

*style.css*

```
body {
    background-color: #FF8C69;
}
.menu.menu-left {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu.content-teste {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
}
.list-custom .item {
    background-color: #FF8C69;
}
```

Comment: Alguem poderia me ajudar como posso alterar o fundo do componente ion-list ?

Comment: Tente mudar a cor do `.item` e `.item a`, exemplo: `.menu .list .item a,.menu .list .item  {background-color:red}`.

Comment: tentei colocar o seguinte :     .list-custom .item{
  background-color: #000000;  
  color: orange;
}  com isso consegui alterar a cor das palavras que estão dentro ion-item, mas a cor de fundo não deu certo. @abfurlan

Comment: @abfurlan o que você sugere? parece como se eu não conseguisse sobrescrever a cor desse componente.

Comment: Tente colocar o cor de fundo no elemento a exemplo: .list-custom .item a { background-color:...

Comment: Seu CSS está sendo carregado após o CSS do ionic?

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajudar @abfurlan , eu coloquei a letra a em todos os meus ion-item e funciono agora a cor de fundo. no css -> .list-custom .item a{
  background-color: #000000;  
  color: orange;
}

Comment: exemplo de como coloquei no ion-list -> <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/secretaria" a>
          Secretaria
        </ion-item> coloquei esse a em todos e ele coloco cor de fundo , muito obrigado pelas dicas. @abfurlan

Comment: Postei como resposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu fiz no html

```
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/principal" a>
          Principal 
</ion-item>
```

eu coloquei o a no ion-item e depois com isso consegui pegar ele no css.

no CSS

```
.list-custom .item a{
  background-color: #000000;  
  color: orange;
}
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação @abfurlan

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa colocar a cor de fundo no elemento `a` filho do elemento `.item`, exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/principal">
   Principal 
</ion-item>
```

Quando o framework renderizar o elemento acima ele transformará em algo como:

```
<li class="item">
    <a href="#/app/principal">Principal</a>
</li>
```

Portanto para estilizar este elemento você precisa aplicar o estilo no elemento `a`.

**CSS**

```
 .list-custom .item a{ background-color: #000000; color: orange; }
```